# Function undefined at non-integer values

Tags: functions, soft-question

Is there a function $f(x)$ which is not defined at integer values?

Please do NOT answer $f(x) = \begin{cases}
  a, & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Z}, \\
  \text{undefined}, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

I thought about $f(x)=x!$ but it turns out $f(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$

So any ideas? Thanks a lot!

---

**P.S.** - I guess $\sqrt{-\{x\}}$ is a solution!

Comment: $x!$ is a function on natural numbers and is not the same as $\Gamma (x+1)$, as they have different domains

Comment: Note that $x!$ is not defined for integers, only for natural numbers, and $\Gamma(x+1)$ is also not defined on negative integers.

Comment: @GFauxPas I know but i don't seem to be able to tell this to a graphing software! Whenever i tell them to graph x!, they show me the graph of $\Gamma(x+1)$

Comment: Which software? Is your question about mathematics or about the program you're using?

Comment: Any function on the integers can be made continuous and differentiable on the reals. So it really is a difficult or meaningless question. There are number-theoretic functions that are likely difficult to naturally be made continuous in a natural way, like the prime-factor counting function.

Comment: Most of the standard number-theoretic functions, such as the number of divisors of $|n|+1$ (the absolute value stuff is a minor fix, to take care of the fact that the number of divisors function is not defined at $0$).

Comment: @GFauxPas http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3Dx%21

Comment: You should provide more information. In fact, question is meaningless.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Why so?

Comment: @NeilRoy, "Is there a function..." Yes, obviously such functions exists. They are trivially, non-trivially, and what? What if I asked you: "is there a numbers differs from 1"? Answer "yes" is bad, "10" is not good. I want "7+3".

Comment: @MichaelGaluza I didnot know about such a function! Sorry for my ignorance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor} $$

The function is defined for all x, except for integers!

Answer (score 1):

For example

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\lfloor\frac{1}{2}(\cos(2 \pi x) + 1) \rfloor}$$

if $x \in \mathbb{Z}$

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\lfloor\frac{1}{2}(1 + 1) \rfloor} = \frac{1}{\lfloor 1 \rfloor} = 1$$

if $x \not \in \mathbb{Z}$

$$-1 \leq \cos(2 \pi x) < 1$$
$$0 \leq \frac{1}{2}(\cos(2 \pi x) + 1) < 1$$

So
$$\lfloor\frac{1}{2}(\cos(2 \pi x) + 1) \rfloor = 0$$

And we get
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{0} $$

which is undefined.

Another function is

$$f(x) = \sqrt{\cos(2 \pi x) - 1}$$